# How to change the Node JS HMAC signature creation to Java

Tags: java, node.js, rest, cryptography, hmacsha1

I am very rarely use Java  and I have an requirement of converting a function in Node.js which builds the HMAC signature for REST POST call to Java

Node JS function :

```
function buildSignature(buf, secret) {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(secret, 'utf8'));
    hmac.update(buf);
    return hmac.digest('hex');
}
```

What I have currently done is:

```
Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
     SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
     sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

     String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
     System.out.println(hash);
```

This is not working out to be the same.

Comment: Can you use a dummy secret, and provide a response for the Node.JS so those only familiar with Java can assist?

Comment: It's my suspicion that hmac.digest('hex'); isn't base 64 encoded. I'd try converting the response of sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()) to hex instead.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java

Comment: Thanks Ryan . This worked ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my suspicion that `hmac.digest('hex');` isn't base 64 encoded. I'd try converting the response of `sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes())` to hex instead.

[How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) 's

The answer I would prefer there (since I use Guava in many projects) is

> final String hex = BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().encode(bytes);

Adapted to your question would be

```
final String hash = BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().encode(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Mac sha256_HMAC;
  sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
  SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
  sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
  byte[] hash = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(payload.getBytes());
  return new String(Hex.encodeHex(hash));
```